# Should I be concerned about painting fiberglass columns darker colors due to warp risk?

Tags: paint, fiberglass

The 10ft wood columns supporting the South-facing portico at the entry to my house rotted out, so I replaced them with fiberglass. The rest of the portico is green with an LRV of 50; I'd like to paint the columns the same color. Yet I have read warnings that fiberglass columns will warp if not painted a light color. Sure enough, most fiberglass columns I see are white or light beige or yellow. Still, I wonder if the warning about warping should be taken seriously, or whether LRV of 50 is out of the danger zone.

Comment: I would call the manufacturer, your location would also be a factor, in Mojave ca it would be different than Newport Or.

Comment: The risk is that the resin which bonds the fiberglass in place will fail due to heat. That's a real issue - the epoxy I use for boat building needs very little heat to cause the bond to permanently fail. Around only 150 degrees F / 60 degrees C. It depends on where you live - but even where I am in Canada, I wouldn't paint an epoxied surface with a dark paint.

Especially since this is a structural application, the conservative choice as I see it would be to use light paint. But check with the manufacturer, maybe they use a heat-resistant resin formulation.